# Does get-childitem lock the folders while fetching files to the last level

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am trying to  read the last leaf based on the lastwritetime in a given folder using get-childitem. Simultaneously few files are getting copied to the same folder. Will this reading the files affect the copy? 
Does the get-childitem lock the root folder while finding the last leaf and prevent the copy of new files into the folder.

Any insight on this is highly helpful.

Regards
Dinesh

Comment: Did You try to check that experimentally ? like `Get-ChildItem -recurse` on some big folder and try to create a file in it in the mean time ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Longer Answer: No, it does not.

`Get-ChildItem` does not lock the file. It may lock if you are using `Get-Content` or something similar in your script with `Get-ChildItem`